# How to use tmux inside release pipeline

Tags: azure, ssh, tmux

I have an azure release pipeline to run my backend application on a DigitalOcean server.

[image: example of what it looks like]

I would like to use a tmux window so I can still see the terminal in case I need to debug the production backend.

```
tmux new-session -A -s tmuxWindowName
pkill java
mv backend/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar backend/backend.jar
java -Xmx800M -jar backend/backend.jar
tmux detach
```

but this doesn't work because the azure ssh connection is not attached to a terminal. I get the following error:

```
##[error]open terminal failed: not a terminal
```

I tried setting the term with "TERM=xterm" and googling this issue comes up with lots of people that are able to manipulate the SSH connection command but I can't since I use an SSH service connection.

What to do?

Comment: i dont think you should attempt to do this, since this should not work at all. thats the idea behind build agents

Comment: Ok. So what can I do to access this terminal later for manual debug purposes?

Comment: nothing. thats the point of build pipelines. they run unattended

Comment: That sucks. I would've liked to have it as a backup in case I need to look at the stacktrace of a failed request.

Comment: you can print it out, it will be visible in the output as long as the job as stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a detached tmux session by adding `-d` to `new-session` which will not require a terminal (until you attach it which will be presumably from somewhere else).

Comment: Are you able to run commands in this detached tmux session from azure? I would like to start the java backend in the tmux session.

Comment: I don't know what azure is so I don't know what you can do with it, but if you can run tmux then you can script it as usual with the `tmux` command, for example `tmux new -d mycommand` to start a new session running `mycommand`. Or `send-keys` to send key presses, `new-window` to make new windows, and so on.